# Elastic PreBuiltTransportClient with spring boot creating memory leakage

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am creating the bean of elastic client using the following code. It's creating the memory leakage. I am using the spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and elastic rest client 5.6.8.

```
@Bean
public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {

    Settings esSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", esClusterName)
            .build();

    return new PreBuiltTransportClient(esSettings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is well known problem.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26048

I think you have one way to solve it

1. You could switch to elastic java rest client. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html

Please check discussion here

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/are-there-memory-leaks-in-elasticsearchs-transportclient-5-4-3-or-is-my-code-flawed/91989